# Getting 404 for authentication API for Xray JIRA Cloud

Tags: api, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I am using JRIA cloud and trying to authenticate by using below API

API Endpoint  https://.atlassian.net/api/v1/authenticate
Header Content-Type : application/json
POST
Body  { "client_id": "<client_id>","client_secret": "<cleint_secret>" }

Getting 404 error code

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint is not correct, in cloud you need to target: `https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate` in order to authenticate.

Replace `https://.atlassian.net/api/v1/authenticate` by `https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate` and it should work.